# template member variable specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I have a `template class` with lots of functions and only want to specialize a few of them, while also adding a member variable.

Is that possible without the need to reimplement all the functions for the specialized class?

---

What I have:

```
template<class T> class Vector3
{
    union {
        T data[3];
        struct { T x, y, z; };
    };

    //a lot of functions

    T Length() { ... };
};
```

What I want to do:

```
template<> class Vector3<float>
{
    union {
        float data[3];
        struct { float x, y, z; };

        //new union member only for <float>!
        __m128 xmm;
    };

    float Length() {
        //special instructions for special case <float>
    };
};
```

As 95% of all functions stay *exactly the same*, I definitely don't want to reimplement them for every single specialization. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you could do is make a helper template that generates a structure-with-union type that is the "core" of your type:

```
template <typename T>
struct Vector3_core {
  union {
    T data[3];
    struct { T x, y, z; };
  };

  T length() { ... }
};
```

and specialize it for `float` as desired:

```
template <>
struct Vector3_core<float> {
  union {
    float data[3];
    struct { float x, y, z; };
    __m128 xmm;
  };

  float Length() { ... }
};
```

Then you could write the main class using simple inheritance like:

```
template<class T> class Vector3 : public Vector3_core<T>
{
  // Need to pull anonymous-struct members into this class' scope
  using Vector3_core<T>::x;
  using Vector3_core<T>::y;
  using Vector3_core<T>::z;

  // All your functions...
};
```

Note that there is no virtual-dispatch going on here. Also, you don't need to make the inheritance public necessarily, you could make it private and forward the `Length` function publicly.

You could also go further and use full-blown CRTP if would be useful.

Here's a code sample on Coliru showing that the idea works at C++11 standard, at least.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef10d0c574a5a040

Comment: Very interresting approach, but am I going right in assuming that i will not be able to directly access the union members as in my first example? So i will have to use impl.x and impl.y ...?

Comment: Edited to address your concern about `impl.x, impl.y` etc.

Comment: Thanks - that is exactly what I've been looking for!